# Error on starting emulator for avd after adt 20 install

Tags: android, android-emulator

I recently installed ADT 20 and SDK Tools r20, now i am having an issue running an emulator on my project. My project targets api 15 and minimum of api 8. I tried deleting and recreating avds but it was no help.

I got this error 
    `X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
       Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
       Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
       Serial number of failed request:  12
       Current serial number in output stream:  12`

does anyone encountered the same issue? any ideas on how to fix would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you running Ubuntu 12.04? I also encounter this problem, and can't start any android version of emulator.

other than answer above, maybe this also help:
[<strike>Is my ati graphics card supported in ubuntu</strike>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu)

[What is the correct way to install ati catalyst video drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers/126513#126513)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this might help, but you can try the link below.

[How to fix error with...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81344/how-to-fix-error-with-ati-driver-error-of-failed-request)